# Crystal Reports Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I have a Windows Forms application that was created in Visual Studio 2008 and targets .NET 3.5. It uses the embedded version of Crystal Reports that comes with VS 2008. It was calling a SQL 2000 database successfully.

The company upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2. The Windows Forms .Net application connections using ADO work fine with the new database. Unfortunately Crystal Reports now hangs. It opens the shell but doesn't open and populate the reports.

Is there a compatibility issue?

Comment: how did you copy the database(s)? data dictionary incompatabilities could have this effect

Comment: I performed a database backup in SQL Server 2000 and restored it SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: if you havent already its worth checking that the report is set up with the correct datasource and that the data definitions in the new database match exactly the former. I suspect though that it might be an issue with the report finding the dbms if it is hanging rather than throwin g

Comment: I did confirm the datasource, what is interesting is on the first run it asked for a username and password to connect. After providing it than just hung. After that reopening didn't prompt for username/password, so it appeared it stored it, it was just wouldn't load the report inside the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were prompted the first time because you have the option checked for 'Verify on First Refresh'.

- Uncheck 'Save data in the report' and save/close.
- Reopen and 'Set Datasource Location...' to new database server.
- Click 'Verify Database'.  (Should recieve success message)
- If still not working 'Set Datasource Location...' to the old database server and verify it works at all.  Then click on 'Show SQL Query' and verify statement returns results on new server by executing query manually.

Comment: When I switched back to the old server the Crystal Reports did work again. I'm using the default port (1433), so I'm referencing the server name as the host.

Comment: What does it say when you 'Verify Database' while pointing to new server?